# how can I catch the small fractional number by regex?

Tags: python, regex, fractions

I want to catch a fractional number using regex. But I still did not find any hint.

For example here in this sentence how can I catch fractional number?

On December 5 following, at 6h in the morning, Mars was seen at 9° 19⅖’ Libra, with a latitude of 1° 53½’ N., the sun being at 23° Sagittarius ^5

I have written a code to catch longitude but I can modify to catch also longitude including fraction number ,here is the code

```
label = "LONG"   
texts = sents  

regex_patterns = [
                  re.compile(r"\d{1,3}\s?°\s?\d{1,2}\s?[\'|’]\s?\d{1,2}\s?[\"|”|“]\s?[A-Z][a-z.]+"   #LONG in format 
                              "|\d{1,3}\s?°\s?\d{1,2}\s?[\'|’]\s?\s?[A-Z][a-z.]+"
                              "|\d{1,3}\s?°\s?\d{1,2}\s?[\'|’]\s?\d{1,2}\s?[\"|”|“]"
                              "|\d{1,3}\s?°\s?\d{1,2}\s?[\'|’]"
                              "|\d{1,3}\s?°\s?[A-Z][a-z.]+")           
]


examples = []
for text in texts:
    for expression in regex_patterns:
        spans = []
    for match in re.finditer(expression, text):
        start, end = match.span()
        span = {"start": start, "end": end, "label": label}
        spans.append(span)
    task = {"text": text, "spans": spans}
    examples.append(task)
```

Comment: Can you specify your desired output? Is it `9° 19⅖'` and `1° 53½'`?

Comment: Those are vulgar fractions and their unicode points can be found at https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/decomposition/%3Cfraction%3E

Comment: yes, I meant those, but I am looking for all of those fractional

Answer (score 3):

You can match unicode characters with the `\uXXXX` tag, where `XXXX` is the hexadecimal code for the unicode character. You can find all the unicode fractions [here](http://unicodefractions.com/).

So for example, if you want to capture every available fraction, you can have this:

```
[\u00BC-\u00BE\u2150-\u215E]
```

So with your example input, you can get:

```
>>> re.findall(r'\d{1,3}\s?°\s?\d{1,2}\s?[\u00BC-\u00BE\u2150-\u215E]?[\'|’]', s)
['9° 19⅖’', '1° 53½’']
```